# C++ Collaboration using Git with different IDEs

Tags: c++, git, ide

I have done a good amount of coding for a C++ school project using Visual Studio 2013. Now, for the next leg, I will be working with another student who uses a Mac.

Git seems the obvious choice to facilitate collaboration (we both have experience with it), however neither of us have collaborated on a C++ project using different IDEs before.

Is there a viable solution to IDE-agnostic collaboration (he will likely use Eclipse), such as including only the .cpp and .h files in Git, or would it be easier in the long run for me to change over to Eclipse?

Comment: you want only .cpp and .h files to be push in git ?

Comment: @AmitK That's the thing, I'm not sure if that would be enough or just cause headaches (e.g. when adding new files to the project). I'm sure I'm not the first one to face this issue, so I'm wondering what kind of solutions others have established.

Comment: you can use .gitignore file and list all the files extensions which you don't want in repo like .obj. and other project specific files.

Comment: @AmitK That I understand, my concern is more with keeping things such as file structure, library includes, etc. synced between the IDEs. What I'm really looking for is advice from someone who has experience with this type of collaboration, but I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a build tool, such as [CMake](https://cmake.org/), and add only the cmake files and source code to version control, and ignore any IDE-specific files. You would then use the import-feature of your IDE to set up the CMake project.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of idea I was looking for, I'll start reading up on CMake. Do you have any suggested reading or tutorials besides the CMake site?